# Path issues installing load2neo

Tags: python, neo4j

I've already parsed my data in a geoff .txt file.

I've downloaded the three files and I've put the two .jar files under

```
/Applications/Neo4j\Community\Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/plugins
```

Since my server folder is located in a different directory, I've added the line:

```
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=com.nigelsmall.load2neo=/load2neo
```

to my configuration file that's at:

```
/Users/Lucas/Documents/Neo4j/testdb/neo4j.properties
```

When I try to start the server I get:

```
Starting Neo4j failed: Multiple exceptions
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm placing files in wrong locations and/or using wrong paths, but I don't have a clue on how to fix it.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: does it give you any information about what the multiple exceptions are? If so could you share that information with us?

Comment: unfortunately that's the only error it shows. ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues:

1.The path given on the configuration file was incorrect, in my case, the correct path was: `org.neo4j.server.database.location=/Users/Lucas/Documents/Neo4j/testdb`

2.I had another process using the port 7474. After I've changed the path to the correct value, the neo4j application gave me a error message about the port being used and I've killed the process with `lsof -i :<port>` and `kill -9 <PID>`

Hope it helps someone (: